# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<username>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I realize there are other similar questions, however I haven't found one that is exactly what I'm having. My issue is that I'm trying to access the Rails dbconsole but it's using the wrong user.

To explain, here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: db/development.mysql2
  user: root
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/test.mysql2
  host: localhost
  user: root
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/production.mysql2
  host: localhost
  user: root
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

When I try and access the console by typing `rails dbconsole`, this is the result:

```
$ rails dbconsole
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'marshallsherman'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I can log in to mysql by typing `$ mysql -uroot -ppassword` AND by typing `$ mysql -umarshallsherman -ppassword`. But when I try and log into the `$ rails dbconsole` it defaults to the "marashallsherman" user, and this is incorrect.

This seems like such a stupid question, however, I don't know how to change the "default" user for the dbconsole so that I can log in with the info that's in my database.yml file.

Help? I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.2

EDIT: I managed to get it so that I can log into the `$ rails dbconsole`, however, it's still logging me in as 'marshallsherman'@'localhost' -- I can't figure out how to switch it to log me in as 'root'@'localhost'.

Comment: MySQL amkes a difference of localhost and real host name .... Maybe having a look into MySQL looks helps you to see, which user@host-combination rails is using here so you can grant access.